# Does Clusterpoint user interface exist for standalone version

Tags: user-interface, clusterpoint

I know that Clusterpoint cloud service has GUI but does its standalone version has the same GUI or GUI at all. And is it the same as in cloud version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, standalone version (v2.3) has it's own GUI to manage databases.  Clusterpoint Cloud has more recent version (v3.x) and has totally new UI. In upcoming months same version which is currently in the cloud will be available for download as well. Specific ETA is not published yet.